# How to collect variables with strcpy

Tags: c, strcpy

I have some problems with collecting variables..

my current code:

```
strcpy (date, year);
strcat (date, "-");
strcat (date, month);
strcat (date, "-");

printf("%s" , date);
```

as result I would like to have `2014-04` for exsample, but currently it gives me `2014-042014-04-`

So for some reason it prints it twice. Someone know what is wrong?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please show how date, year and month are allocated and initialized.

Comment: Null terminating your string is your friend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: Ditto's on the lack of information. Possible issues include: date too small, month not terminated with null.

Comment: they are in {char *year} and {char *month} after user gives them and char date[64] collecting them

Comment: @hyde: that is *not* how `strcat` works. The OP is using the correct syntax so the problem lies in Code Not Shown.

Comment: @Jongware Ah-ha, seems reading with mobile browser somehow messed the output mentioned in question to just `2014-04-`... I was already starting to suspect my own sanity when nobody else saw anything funny with that.

Comment: I suspect the bug is that year is incorrect and is "2014-04". Just print month and year and that should shed more light on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the problem by letting `printf` do the work instead of trying to assemble the string yourself:

```
int year = 2014;
int month = 4;
printf("%04i-%02i", year, month);
```

In general, it's not a good idea to use `strcat`.  It's prone to buffer overruns, and is deprecated in newer versions of the C standard.  Using `printf` means you don't need the intermediate `date` buffer, avoiding problems related to buffer overruns, missing NULL termination, etc.

If you want the result in a variable instead of printing it out, simply replace `printf` with `snprintf`:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_LEN] = {0};
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%04i-%02i", year, month);
```

Comment: This would work otherside but I'm trying to collect new variable and with it search from database.. sorry didn't mention it :/

Comment: @user3665673 Note that while this (updated version) may well "fix" your code to produce the correct output, it seems you are having either overlapping strings, or string which aren't properly nul-terminated. It'd be good idea to get your original code working too, even if you also change your code to use `snprintf` like shown here (which would be good too).

Comment: Using `strcat()` can sometimes cause issues, but it's not deprecated in any version of the C standard.

Comment: I thought C11 deprecated `strcat` in favor of `strcat_s`.  I must have remembered incorrectly.